# 1 предлагаемых правок ожидают утверждения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Я не носитель русского языка, и вполне возможно, что я ошибаюсь, но мне кажется, что вместо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> 1 предлагаемых правок ожидают утверждения

должно быть

> 1 предлагаемая правка ожидает утверждения

Наверно есть похожая ошибка если количество правок равно 2, 3, 21, 22, 23, и т.д.

Comment: Не носитель русского языка, правда? Свободно очень общаетесь, я никогда бы не подумал.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, поправил перевод. В ближайшем обновление движка недочет будет исправлен.

Answer (score 4):

Просто движок не обрабатывает числительные склонения в русском языке, по всей видимости. Да, выглядит немного "неграмотно", но мы, носители языка, пожалуй что и привыкли уже видеть такое. Лично я воспринимаю спокойно, но для филологов в душе можно исправить на что то вроде:

> Правок, ожидающих утверждения: 1 (2, 3, 15 ... )

Comment: Но у нас нормальное склонение в других местах, 1 ответ, 2 ответа, 5 ответов, и показ, показа, показов, знак, знака, знаков, и т.д. Зачем здесь не делать также?

Comment: Только последнее предложение в комментарии выдало "неносителя" языка :)

Answer (score 4):

Теперь в транзифексе есть соответствующие строки для разного числа.

Строки о правках давным-давно исправил Nicolas Chabanovsky:

> ~$pendingEdits$ suggested edits pending approval
>   1 предлагаемая правка ожидает утверждения
>   2 предлагаемые правки ожидают утверждения
>   5 предлагаемых правок ожидают утверждения

Сегодня я также поправил и немного упростил формулировки для другого сообщения, которое появляется в том же месте:

> $pendingReviews$ total posts awaiting review
>   1 сообщение ожидает проверки
>   2 сообщения ожидают проверки
>   5 сообщений ожидают проверки