# Статистика проверяющего: «4 предлагаемых правок»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[Страница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/103899):

> [image: 4 предлагаемых правок]

«2 отклонённые правки» в правильном падеже, «4 предлагаемых правок» нет. Видимо, когда [исправляли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2396/199934), упустили цифру 4 из виду.

Comment: Там я другие строки правил.

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас проблема [не проявляется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/216697) (исправлена):

> [image: 4 правки]